# base subtotal including tax

Tags: cart, tax, totals

I need to get base subtotal including tax. This

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getBaseSubtotal()
```

will show subtotal without tax, even if config Display Subtotal is set to Including tax.

This

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$totals["subtotal"]->getValue()
```

will show subtotal with tax (if config Display Subtotal is set to Including tax).

But I can not find any method to display base subtotal with tax. Does anybody have any idea?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way:

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$rate = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData('base_to_quote_rate');
$subtotalIncTax = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue()/$rate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$tax = $quote->getGrandTotal() - $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
```

EDIT:

I just found a more elegant solution:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getTaxAmount();
```

Comment: There is no such data inside the object, it returns null.

Comment: Hmm, you need to check all the attributes on the object then. Try: `print_r(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData())`

Comment: I already checked it and I don't find any useful information excepting base_to_quote_rate. But if I want to use this data I need to calculate default currency in reverse order which I am not sure how.

Comment: The new code should work

Comment: Thank you but this is wrong. Grand total is different than subtotal. Grand total calculates also discounts which is not included in subtotal. You can not calculate subtotal from grandtotal.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: The same goes for getShippingAddress()->getTaxAmount(), it has discount already calculated and you can not get subtotal from it.